Where to add setComputeUnitLimit and setComputeUnitPrice so we can adjust fees?
as you know solana Congestion has happened for days now, and i can't get anything trough. I was trying to do a metadata initialization and update, but it keeps failing.
i'm a newbie, did a bit of python before, but Typescript is new for me, and I can't seem to get it right.
i have got this little piece
const accounts: CreateMetadataAccountV3InstructionAccounts = {
    mint: fromWeb3JsPublicKey(mint),
    mintAuthority: signer,
}
const data: CreateMetadataAccountV3InstructionDataArgs = {
    isMutable: true,
    collectionDetails: null,
    data: onChainData
}
const txid = await createMetadataAccountV3(umi, { ...accounts, ...data }).sendAndConfirm(umi);
console.log(txid)

my question is how do i add the parameters for setComputeUnitLimit and setComputeUnitPrice ?
i tried using .add() before .sendAndConfirm(umi) but doesn't seem to work.

you want to add compute Budget price.
import { transactionBuilder } from '@metaplex-foundation/umi'
import { setComputeUnitPrice } from '@metaplex-foundation/mpl-toolbox'

const txid = await createMetadataAccountV3(umi, { ...accounts, ...data })
.prepend(setComputeUnitPrice(umi, { microLamports: 1 }))
.sendAndConfirm(umi);

More information can be found in the Metaplex Developer Hub.
Just as additional information: It is way easier to use the helper functions that the @metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata package provides so that you do not have to first mint the token, find accounts and data args manually etc.. For example you can use the createFungible helper:
const createFungibleIx = createFungible(umi, {
  mint: mintSigner,
  name: 'The Kitten Coin',
  uri: metadataUri,
  sellerFeeBasisPoints: percentAmount(0),
  decimals: 9, // set the amount of decimals you want your token to have.
})

